# Tree type is not supported

Tags: angular, shell

I installed Angular/cli globally on my ubuntu trusty machine, but I can't create a new project:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/projects/tools/angular-app$ ng -v

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.1.3
Node: 10.7.0
OS: linux x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.7.3
@angular-devkit/core         0.7.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.7.3
@schematics/angular          0.7.3
@schematics/update           0.7.3
rxjs                         <error>

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/projects/tools/angular-app$ npm view @angular/cli

@angular/cli@6.1.3 | MIT | deps: 10 | versions: 157
CLI tool for Angular
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

keywords: angular, Angular CLI, devkit, sdk, Angular DevKit, angular-cli

bin: ng

dist
.tarball https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/cli/-/cli-6.1.3.tgz
.shasum: a4cc751c96423cea17628d94c1419d334d7adfbf
.integrity: sha512-S0uVQKKWETeX/mZ0WEZ2f+4xHArEtJ1hRl4GWKZEzU+vpptVnUXDDLC5aiN1ArfEcI1TShDsdhRSYSfccif2xA==
.unpackedSize: 509.7 kB

dependencies:
@angular-devkit/architect: 0.7.3  @angular-devkit/schematics: 0.7.3 @schematics/update: 0.7.3         rxjs: ^6.0.0                      symbol-observable: ^1.2.0
@angular-devkit/core: 0.7.3       @schematics/angular: 0.7.3        opn: ^5.3.0                       semver: ^5.1.0                    yargs-parser: ^10.0.0

maintainers:
- angular <angular-core+npm@google.com>
- angular-cli <hansl@google.com>

dist-tags:
latest: 6.1.3       next: 6.2.0-beta.2

published 11 hours ago by angular <devops+npm@angular.io>
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/projects/tools/angular-app$ ng new dsi-ui
Tree type is not supported.
```

I have an empty folder: angular-app where I want to create the new project, but I keep getting the error: `Tree type is not supported`.

I followed the github issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11707 but it doesn't work for me. I also tried to uninstall angular, clear npm cache and install again but I get the same error still.
 Any clues?